# facebook "recent activity" feed showing no or very few results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-activity

I am a front end programmer for smartplanet.com and we are experiencing some rather off phenomena  with our recent activity feed from the facebook api.  for reference, an example page would be as follows:   (http://www.smartplanet.com/blog/cities/get-paid-to-avoid-traffic-jams/3650)

Based on the [debugger tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smartplanet.com%2Fblog%2Fcities%2Fget-paid-to-avoid-traffic-jams%2F3650) on the dev website, our open graph tagging seems marginally correctly implemented, other than a warning regarding image size, but I fail to see how that could contribute to this issue.

[This](http://www.facebook.com/plugins/activity.php?border_color=%23fff&font=arial&header=false&height=350&linktarget=_blank&locale=en_US&recommendations=false&ref=activity-widget&sdk=joey&site=www.smartplanet.com&width=290) is the direct link being used to fetch the data from the facebook platform. 
As you can see upon refreshing this url multiple times we get a pretty wide variety of results, but more times than not we are seeing 0-2 results come back.

I found that [adding a max_age optional parameter](http://www.facebook.com/plugins/activity.php?border_color=%23fff&font=arial&header=false&height=350&linktarget=_blank&locale=en_US&recommendations=false&ref=activity-widget&sdk=joey&site=www.smartplanet.com&width=290&max_age=10) to the call garnishes MUCH better results, but I dont understand WHY this is fixing the problem.

The previous link is for a max age of 10 days and gets great results, but if I increase that to the maximum time span(as per the facebook documentation) of 180, we go back to [very limited results](http://www.facebook.com/plugins/activity.php?border_color=%23fff&font=arial&header=false&height=350&linktarget=_blank&locale=en_US&recommendations=false&ref=activity-widget&sdk=joey&site=www.smartplanet.com&width=290&max_age=180).

While I can patch the site and limit to a lower max age, it does not explain WHY any of this is happening.  It is my understanding that by omitting the max_age parameter you remove age as a factor for the retrieved data completely, so how can a larger data set of content pull back LESS results and do so consistently?

Any insight as to what is occurring here would be greatly appreciated.

As a side note a nearly identical implementation is used on another of our sites(zdnet.com) without the max_age parameter and works flawlessly.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

check out the below link.
[http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/][1]

I was wondering to list Recent Activity feed of a FB Page for website. I found Social Plugin @fb dev corner.. May be useful to you!!

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome in Stack Overflow. Show some information here.